# Is this Dynamic polymorphism or not?

Tags: java, type-conversion, polymorphism, inner-classes, private-methods

The output of the program is **A** isn't it suppose to be **B**. If I change the modifier of method in **Class A** to **public** then the output is **B**. Can somebody explain what is going on here?

**Code:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        hw.createInstance();
    }

    public void createInstance() {
        A b = new B();
        b.isTrue();
    }
    
    public class A {
        private void isTrue() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
    public class B extends A {
        public void isTrue() { 
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** A

Answer (score 2):

If `isTrue()` in A was public, then `isTrue()` in B would override it. (Overriding means if you call a method declared in the base class, the matching method in the subclass is executed.)

In this case, since `isTrue()` in A is private, the two `isTrue()` methods are independent. Private methods are not subject to overriding.

Since you are calling `isTrue()` on a variable of type A, it is the `isTrue()` method in A that is executed. Being private does not, in this case, prevent you accessing the method, because all your code is inside one class, `HelloWorld`. If your classes were not inner (or nested) classes, then you wouldn't be able to call the private method from outside the class it is declared in.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a B instance, pointed by an A Instance.
As A isTrue is private, the compiler will raise an error

If you make A.isTrue() public, as you created a B instance it will execute B isTrue method, as that method is overridden

Due your classes are inner classes, when you call isTrue pointed by A class it executes isTrue from A and does not apply the override because the methods have different visibility. When you make isTrue from A public it applies polymorphism as they have the same modifier.

The confussion is because they are inner classes, if they weren't inner classes your code won't compile

Comment: _As A isTrue is private, the compiler will raise an error_
-there is no compilation error [link](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/#&togetherjs=LB2lEOyif6)